# Batch : Why does for loop return empty when it is placed in if else clause?

Tags: batch-file

I have this code in my .bat file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

//Run sqlcmd command to backup file

//error handler for sqlcmd
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0(
    FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR /s "D:\Temp\*.bak" /b /O:D') DO set latestFile=%%I
    echo %latestFile%
) else (
    echo Error occured.
)
```

### Problem

The result that I always got from `echo %latestFile%` is always `ECHO is off` meaning, the `%%I` is empty. However, when I move the for loop to outside of the `if-else` clause and used `goto` to execute the for loop, this problem does not occur.

Comment: You're explicitly turning *off* delayed expansion, and then running a command that needs delayed expansion.  Enable it and then use `echo !latestFile!`  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the CMD parser reads and parses an entire statement block inside parentheses before executing it.  This means all variable expansion in the entire block happens before any commands are run.  [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993/) is a deeper explanation why this works this way.

To get around this, CMD supports *Delayed Expansion*, which allows variables to be re-parsed before each line in a statement block.  The syntax for this is `!variable!`.

First, you need to *enable* delayed expansion, by changing your setlocal line from `disabledelayedexpansion` to `enabledelayedexpansion`.   Second, you need to change your echo line to use `!` instead of `%`

```
REM @echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

//Run sqlcmd command to backup file

//error handler for sqlcmd
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0(
    FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR /s "D:\Temp\*.bak" /b /O:D') DO set latestFile=%%I
    echo !latestFile!
) else (
    echo Error occured.
)
```

Finally, note that `@echo off` suppresses debugging information, and you should always remove or comment that line while debugging.  It often makes the difference between having to guess which line failed and knowing.